# AD iis basic authentication , disabled account handle

Tags: active-directory, iis

i have a website that uses basic authentication through Active Directory. everything works great, however, when an account is either locked or disabled, the user just keeps getting the pop up box, so they don't know what's going on. is it possible to somehow redirect them to a proper error page, or give some more detail? instead of just having the pop up box come up again and again and again..

Comment: When a domain account authenticates to a domain resource and that credential cannot authenticate successfully to a site that authenticates with Windows or Intergrated authentication due to account lockout, expire, disable, etc. then this will happen oobviously as it's not like you're allowing it to be accessed anonymously.... I'll put two articles in the below comment for a starting point and then just narrow down a specific solution for your environment with the languages you're coding the site with, etc. (e.g ASP.net).

Comment: [**Resource 1**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11202/Redirecting-to-custom-page-when-quot-Access-de) and [**Resource 2**](http://serverfault.com/questions/139092/iis-redirect-to-a-webpage-if-authentication-fails). . . Do further reading and testing to confirm such a solution will work in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the environment to test this right now, but I came across error page codes of which contain "401.1 - Logon failed". As long as you have above IIS7.
From the home of IIS in IIS section choose Error Pages and set this code and path to the htm file.

C:\inetpub\custerr\en-US\401-1.htm

Then try failing login again.

Comment: it never gets to an error page of any kind, the login prompt just keeps popping back up.

Comment: It might not come up becuasethere is no error page response for a failure. Try adding a 401.1 error page and see if it comes up upon a lock out now.